# Styling links with hover state background change

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style some sub-category links so that the entire background acts as a link and when hovered turns the black text on a yellow background to white text on a black background.

Website https://www.toys4cars.co.uk/bmw-roof-racks.html

```css
h2.product-name2 {
  background-color: #FFE51E;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
.product-name2:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="product-name2">
    <a href="http://www.toys4cars.co.uk/bmw-1-series-roof-racks.html" title="1 Series" class="product-image"></a>
    <a href="http://www.toys4cars.co.uk/bmw-1-series-roof-racks.html" title="1 Series">1 Series</a>
</h2>
```

Could I have some pointers please as to how this is accomplished.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some of the relevant css?

Comment: At present on hover the text acts as the link where as I would prefer the entire box to be the link. Also the text color changes to black unless you are hovering over it which makes it look as though the text has disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this seems to do the trick when inspecting:

```
h2.product-name2 a {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2.product-name2 {
  background-color: #FFE51E;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.product-name2:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
h2.product-name2 a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2.product-name2:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="product-name2">
    <a href="http://www.toys4cars.co.uk/bmw-1-series-roof-racks.html" title="1 Series">1 Series</a>
</h2>
```

The critical changes here were to 1) make the anchors block-level, 2) remove the redundant anchor markup, and 3) set color on the anchors rather than the heading.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/3jum371q/) to highlight the dynamic changes I see on the site that you asked about, I will elaborate as I go so please feel free to ask more questions.

HTML

```
<div>
    section 1
</div>
<div>
    section 2
</div>
<div>
    section 3
</div>
<div>
    section 4
</div>
<div>
    section 5
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using javascript instead of the CSS pseudo selector `:hover`?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I've been working on jQuery for a bit too long lately, the little things!

Answer (score 0):

Target your anchor when the whole background is hovered.

```css
h2.product-name2:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```